# Selenium webdriver loads a blank page instead of the target URL

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, crx

I wanted to add to my working program some code in order to open the chrome browser with an extension already enabled, but since I added it, the browser starts with the extension enabled and, instead of the target URL, it loads a blank page that has written just "data;" on the Url bar. 
I'm pretty sure that the problem is referred to the code I added to the previous program because, if I delete it, the program runs fine but without the extension.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

executable_path = "path to the chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = executable_path

buster = webdriver.ChromeOptions()    # buster is the extension I want to add
buster.add_extension('path to buster.crx')

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path, options=buster)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
```

Comment: which operating system is using linux or windows

Comment: I use Windows @bharatk

Comment: I am using Linux.  You should set chrome web drive path like : driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromedriver")

Comment: @bharatk It doesn't work because the program finds and opens the webdriver file, it simply seems to the end the code to the second to last line, excluding the line "driver.get(...)"

Comment: You should change the chrome web drive path as per your system installation.

Comment: @bharatk the problem is not the webdriver path