# python selenium driver.get() opens a blank page for google webdriver instead of the actual url in Windows

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've a Windows 10, 64 bit system.

My simple selenium code below runs without exception/error, but opens a blank page instead of opening `google.com` and its the same behavior with any url, not only `google.com` :

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


#Chrome browser version 91.0.4472.77
# Crome-Driver version used: 91.0.4472.19 <--latest

url='https://www.google.co.in/'
driver_path='F:\Path\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= driver_path, options= chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
```

Output I get:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFhcr.png)

Can someone tell me , what's going on here ? I have written selenium codes before (on different machines though), but never faced such elementary issues, and having no clue how to solve it, because of the code reporting no error at all.

I did go through some other related questions posted, but don't see any answers/solutions posted ther as well:

[Selenium webdriver loads a blank page instead of the target URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56112327/selenium-webdriver-loads-a-blank-page-instead-of-the-target-url)

Comment: see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59717738/chrome-page-opened-with-selenium-remains-blank

Comment: @itronic1990 This actually helped. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code that worked for me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


class user_login:

    def __init__(self,path,url):

        self.path = path
        self.url = url
        self.setup = None

    def chrome_setup(self):

        try:
            options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            options.add_argument("start_maximized")
            options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
            self.chrome_driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=self.path, options=options)
            self.chrome_driver.implicitly_wait(20)
            print("Chrome Driver Loaded")
        except Exception as e:
            print("exception is: " + str(e))

        else:
            self.setup = True
            self.load_url()


    def load_url(self):

        if self.setup is True:

            try:
                print("Loading URL")
                self.chrome_driver.get(self.url)
                
            except Exception as e:
                print(str(e))
                

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
     
    url='/path/to/my/url'
    driver_path='/path/to/my/chromedriver.exe'
    obj = user_login(driver_path,url)
    obj.chrome_setup()
```

Please note, I structured the code into `classes` and `methods`, just to increase readability which would help me debug the code.

But the main change is I had to explicitly mention the binary location to my `chrome.exe` i.e the chrome browser's exe file. This is the code line: `options.binary_location = r"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"`

The `implicit wait` is optional but a good practice, hence I added it : `self.chrome_driver.implicitly_wait(20)`. But without it also just the above code change, made the code work like a charm.

Answer (score -2):

Super easy mistake to make when starting out with selenium, the way you would fix this is by adding `driver.get(url)` earlier in your program

Comment: @himynamesis I don't understand. My code has the line you mentioned

Comment: You do but its at the end, that means once you run through all of your code then you enter the url. You need one of the first lines to be the url or else selenium will by default open a tab that just says data.

Comment: @himynamesis Where do u suggest this line in the code then ?

Comment: I would suggest putting it right after you define the driver path.

Comment: What is the error message that you are getting